# Adding Category Filter in DAX of PowerBI

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

This may be a basic question but I am kind of stuck at it.

I have series of dax written to find an employee turnover.

It works on following formula.

```
Employees left / (Employee at start of year + Emp at end of year)/2 * 100.
```

It just works fine except that in the dax that calculates "Employees Left", it looks upon all the leavers while against every leaver, there's a column called "STATUS" that checks why the Employee left. It could be termination, or resignation, or Retirement.

I want to add a filter to the dax which finds Employees left only against "Resignations"

```
Employees who left =

VAR selectedDate = LASTDATE('Date'[Date])
VAR selectedDate12MonthsBefore = NEXTDAY(SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(selectedDate))

RETURN
SUMX(NEW_Turnover_ADS,
IF(NEW_Turnover_ADS[LAST_WORKING_DATE]>=selectedDate12MonthsBefore && NEW_Turnover_ADS[LAST_WORKING_DATE]<=selectedDate, 1, 0)
)
```

I am currently using this dax.

I tried something as follow but it doesnt works.

```
Employees who left filter =

VAR selectedDate = LASTDATE('Date'[Date])
VAR selectedDate12MonthsBefore = NEXTDAY(SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR(selectedDate))

RETURN
SUMX(FILTER(NEW_Turnover_ADS, NEW_Turnover_ADS[HR_STATUS] = 'RESIGNATION', NEW_Turnover_ADS,
IF(NEW_Turnover_ADS[LAST_WORKING_DATE]>=selectedDate12MonthsBefore && NEW_Turnover_ADS[LAST_WORKING_DATE]<=selectedDate, 1, 0)
) )))))
```

Any help in this regard would be appreciated.

**Please note I only need to add filter by category in above dax - rest is working fine.**

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your attempt seems reasonable except for syntax errors.

Try this:

```
Employees who left =
VAR selectedDate = LASTDATE ( 'Date'[Date] )
VAR selectedDate12MonthsBefore = NEXTDAY ( SAMEPERIODLASTYEAR ( selectedDate ) )
RETURN
    SUMX (
        FILTER (
            NEW_Turnover_ADS,
            NEW_Turnover_ADS[HR_STATUS] = "RESIGNATION"
        ),
        IF (
            NEW_Turnover_ADS[LAST_WORKING_DATE] >= selectedDate12MonthsBefore
                && NEW_Turnover_ADS[LAST_WORKING_DATE] <= selectedDate,
            1,
            0
        )
    )
```

Comment: hey, thanks for reply, it returns an error which says ``cannot find table 'RESIGNATION'``

Comment: Whoops. It needs double quotes. I’ll edit in a bit.

Comment: ahh! i added ``"`` and it worked. thanks man